# Displaying Image from XML into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, image

I have tried to display the following image onto the html, however to no avail. When the html is loaded, it displays the picture icon, but it won't display the image itself. I have copied the code below

Thanks.

HTML Code:

```
 <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TEST");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("imageurl")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write(img.src);
document.body.appendChild(img);
}
document.write("</table>");


</script>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST_GROUP>
    <TEST>
        <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
        <imageurl>"CFL_175x175.png"</imageurl>
    </TEST>

</TEST_GROUP>
```

Comment: If a placeholder is displaying instead of the image, then the HTML cannot *see* the image file. In Chrome, right-click on the image and choose "Inspect Element". In displayed source, hover over link to img file. If image does not pop-up, check path. Note that you can click on / change the link path in this source code to try to identify correct path. Use FileZilla (or etc) to verify path to image file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<imageurl>CFL_175x175.png</imageurl>
```